# Modularization & reuse of code written using Ext JS

Tags: javascript, extjs, dependencies, reusability, modularization

I need clarity into being able to modularize my JavaScript code that leverages Ext JS. My objective is to create custom classes that extend Ext JS widgets, distribute code among several JavaScript files (.js files).

I have looked into documentation on `Ext.Loader` but I didn't quite follow the approach to ensure class dependency resolution. My code in a single JavaScript file is working as desired, given that the code sequentialization is as per dependency. But once I break the code in several JavaScript files and want to use in multiple pages, my dependency is in a disarray as all my pages require different classes with varied dependencies.

Considering that I easily achieve code separation and reuse quite easily in regular backend coding, this has baffled me. Please help with inputs. I'm using Ext JS 4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

To enable dependency resolution when creating custom components, use the `requires` param of `Ext.define`. It looks like this:

```
Ext.define("My.custom.Widget", {
    alias: "widget.mywidget",
    requires: [
        "My.custom.TextField",
        "My.custom.ComboBox",
        "My.custom.Store"
    ],
    constructor: function(config){}
    /* ... */
});
```

For more information, you should read [Dynamic Loading and New Class System](http://www.sencha.com/blog/countdown-to-ext-js-4-dynamic-loading-and-new-class-system) from the Sencha website. It goes into more detail about how dynamic loading works. It's actually really cool once you get the hang of it.

Almost forgot. You can explicitly call `Ext.require` to load certain files when you need them. It supports wildcards, aliases and such. There's also `Ext.exclude` to prevent certain files from loading.

Comment: Just to note here that if Loader is enabled you do not have to explicitly use requires or require methods if you use the naming convention and MVC pattern described in the guides.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha has some really great guides to help you master the framework.
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide

A good one to start with is this one: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture Application Architecture. This guide clearly shwos you how to modularize you code and the folder structure the Loader is expecting.
Please have a look at it.